# SQLSTATE[42000] Exceptions on reindex

Tags: magento-1, magento-enterprise, reindex

I updated my MAMP site from EE 1.14.1.0 to EE 1.14.2.0. After updating, I also applied the new patch for PHP 7. The site also has all of the required SUPEES. When I try and do a reindexall command inside of terminal, I get the following error an **all** indexes except for Product Attributes and Tag Aggregation Data:

```
Catalog Search Index index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 3057 Incorrect user-level lock name 'dbname.index_process_ee93898b-dd2e-11e8-89b2-d28213db0fb8'.' in lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT IS_USED_...', Array)
#5 lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT IS_USED_...', Array)
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(83): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT IS_USED_...', Array)
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock/Storage/Db.php(96): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->isLocked('dbname...')
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php(257): Mage_Index_Model_Lock_Storage_Db->isLockExists('index_process_e...')
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php(227): Mage_Index_Model_Lock->_isLockExistsDb('index_process_e...')
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(480): Mage_Index_Model_Lock->isLockExists('index_process_e...', NULL)
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(184): Mage_Index_Model_Process->isLocked()
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#15 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 3057 Incorrect user-level lock name 'dbname.index_process_ee93898b-dd2e-11e8-89b2-d28213db0fb8'., query was: SELECT IS_USED_LOCK(?);' in lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT IS_USED_...', Array)
#4 lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT IS_USED_...', Array)
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(83): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT IS_USED_...', Array)
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock/Storage/Db.php(96): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->isLocked('dbname...')
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php(257): Mage_Index_Model_Lock_Storage_Db->isLockExists('index_process_e...')
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Lock.php(227): Mage_Index_Model_Lock->_isLockExistsDb('index_process_e...')
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(480): Mage_Index_Model_Lock->isLockExists('index_process_e...', NULL)
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(184): Mage_Index_Model_Process->isLocked()
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#14 {main}
```

In MAMP, I have selected the version of PHP to be 7.2.8.

I have tried to delete the files inside of var/locks.

I have tried applying SUPEE-5984, which was suggested a couple of posts here.

I also tried to truncate the

1. catalog_product_flat_1 and
2. catalog_product_flat_cl tables, which was also suggested.

Use Flat Catalog Category is set to 'No' in my configuration.

Comment: What database are you using? I found [this issue](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/385) for the Go SQL driver and [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1555503) for Percona.

Comment: @Mike - I am using Sequel Pro. I will see if there is anything out there about that database.

Comment: I tried to start the process all over again, by duplicating my EE 1.14.1.0 site. I tested reindexing at the start and it worked. However, when I tried to duplicate it a second time (from the initial database), I got the same error as above. Could this be an issue in Sequel Pro and duplicating a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue was because I had deleted a database in Sequel Pro and then created a database with the same name.

When I created a new database with a name that hadn't been previously used, I no longer had this issue.